# Finding a weird symbol in Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm currently trying to find a symbol on a page. I have the HTML tag and the find method that I'm using. However it's not able to find this symbol. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to do so.

```
<div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok clickable bg-pristine bg-valid bg-scope bg-not-empty bg-touched" bg-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" tabindex="0" bg-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)" bg-keydown="selectButtonKeyDown(row, $event)" role="checkbox" bg-model="row.isSelected" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false">&nbsp;</div>
```

As you can see this is a weird html tag. I'm trying to avoid full xpath if possible.

Here is what I"m doing.

```
find(:css, "ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons[button = 'selectButtonClick']")
```

Comment: To solve the problem in a non-brittle fashion you really need to look at the HTML this element, is there a parent/ancestor element with an id or test-id which can be used to scope? Are there siblings which can be used to scope, etc.  Updating your question with a larger block of HTML would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

To identify the symbol on the page you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
find(:css, ".ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons[bg-click^='selectButtonClick']")
```

or

```
find(:css, ".ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons[bg-model$='isSelected']")
```